# Espresso tests not working with new Google Android Emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-testing, android-espresso, android-studio-2.0

About a month ago I upgraded to Android Studio 2.0 after being on 1.5 for quite a while. I have a suite of 23 tests built on top of Espresso that drive my app.

Normally, I use Genymotion Pro but I have been trying to get a CI server going and I wanted to use the "new and improved" Google Android Emulators.

Today I finally got around to trying the new emulators. I was pleasantly surprised after installing my app and playing with it.

My optimism quickly faded when I went to run my tests via Android Studio. Here are some of the problems I encountered:

- The test took a ridiculous amount of time to install and sometimes hung for over 5 minutes at which point I would close them.
- The emulator restarts itself between every test. This adds a considerable amount of time to total execution. Sometimes when restarting it just freezes up and I have to close it.
- Tests failing randomly for no reason.
- After a test finishes running sometimes the emulator just hangs on a black screen for a long time. Sometimes for so long I just kill the emulator.
- After the tests do finish the emulator is often unresponsive and broken.

Note that **none of the above ever** happens with Genymotion.

Some additional info:

- My machine is a MacBook Air running Yosemite (10.10.5)
- My app uses the newest versions of all SDK dependencies right now.
- Animations are turned off on the Emulators
- I am compiling with Java 1.8 and using RetroLambda (I don't see why this would matter but who knows)
- I am pretty confident that my Espresso tests ran smoothly on the pre-2.0 Emulators, but it has been at least a month since I would have done that and I can't say for sure. I will probably downgrade and try it out if nothing else works.
- Log cat hasn't provided me with any useful info when all of this is happening.
- Tests work fine on real devices connected via USB.

Things I have tried:

- I thought it was possible that this was an issue with Android Studio. Alas, with Gradle on the command line the same issues occur.
- I have tried a bunch of different variations of device type and ABI version, the problem occurs on all of them.
- I downloaded a few Espresso sample projects from Github. I experienced the same issue with all these projects, indicating that this probably isn't an issue with my particular Espresso setup.
- Deleting old emulators and making new ones.
- Coworkers have replicated the issue across machines (all macs of various kinds)

I am perplexed by this. Is anyone else experiencing the same thing? Is there anyway I can get the Google Android Emulators to run tests in a useful way?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey everyone, I appreciate the upvotes. I am assuming they are out of pity but, if you are experiencing this issue too, I would love for you to leave a comment here so we can exchange notes!

Comment: Are you running the release build for 2.0.0, or a beta?

Comment: @stkent release, in `About Android Studio` it says `Android Studio 2.0 Build #AI-143.2739321, built on April 5, 2016`

Comment: Have you installed Intel x86 emulator accelerator HAXM? Check in android SDK manager. I have no any issues with new emulators.

Comment: @JaredAndrews more pity votes! :p

Comment: Also, my case is that tests fail intermittently on emulators when run in a CI environment (Travis). If I simply restart the jobs, previously failing tests will pass. After a lot of searching and debugging, I concluded that this is happening due to slow speed of emulators. Adding appropriate waits in tests fixed most of them for me.. Except a few. This is one of the tests that randomly keeps failing on Android 29. https://github.com/ashutoshgngwr/noice/blob/c00cf1a3ec2cd51cbd47b62d876700b2bf654392/app/src/androidTest/java/com/github/ashutoshgngwr/noice/MainActivityTest.kt#L74-L103